# Trouble Implementing JQuery Filter

Tags: jquery, html

I have some JQuery that filters a table when the select list is changed using `:contains` but because two of the options are so similar it doesn't filter correctly. Here is a functional [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Xjkn/2/). I tried implementing a `.filter` but I obviously am doing something wrong. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Xjkn/3/)

**Current `.filter`**

```
$(this).filter(function(){
    return $(this).text===selectValue;
}).addClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text` is a method not a property, you are comparing the `text` function's body with the selected value. According to your markup I would suggest:

```
$("#filterItems .hideThis").addClass('hidden').filter(function() {
    return $('td:eq(3)', this).text() === selectValue;
}).removeClass('hidden');
```

Note that you can also use the jQuery's `show` and `hide` methods instead of adding/removing classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/24eTW/

Comment: Thank you that is pretty great!

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this).text()` to get the value, just using the handler without the parantheses will return the function rather than executing it